# Dijkstra Monotonic Path

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, dijkstra

I do have a question related to checking if the shortest path is strictly monotonic using Dijkstra.

Edges connected to each node are sorted and stored inside a `LinkedList<Edge> edges;`
The `shortestPathMap` is a utility to store the entire path from starting node to the end node.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to check if a path is monotonic, or force search to select monotonic next edge ?

Comment: @c0der the final result should be a strictly monotonic shortest path

Comment: could you post the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: Each Edge has source, destination and weight, each node has a List of connected Edges, Graph contains info about the Nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a strictly monotonic shortest path can be done by relaxing edges in order based on their weight.

Say we want to find the shortest ascending path. We would order the edges in ascending order, then relax them in that order. "Relax" just means update the weight of the node at the endpoint of an edge to be the weight of the edge plus the weight of its start point node if that sum is less than the current value. This is the same as relaxing an edge in Dijkstra's. This will always yield the shortest ascending path (and it can be made *strictly* ascending if we update the node weights at the same time for all equally valued edges).

We can also find the shortest descending path by ordering edges in descending order. One of those two paths will be the shortest monotonic path.

I think you will have more luck using this approach of looping over the sorted edges (in n logn time) than trying to loop over the nodes as in the above method -- if you need to solve the problem by only updating the method you have shown us, it becomes a much harder problem.

Comment: sure, I understand that. The edges for each node are in descending order. Do you mean to get all edges in some ordered list; then relax the edges; and assuming we have all nodes weights updated, what next?
Is it possible that you'll update the code snippet above to show your logic?

Comment: see also the comment above about what Edge, Node and Graph structures contain.

Comment: First you set the node weights to max_value except the start node, then get all the edges in the graph in a single ordered list, then relax them in that order. Once you have done that, each node's weight will be the shortest distance via monotonic path's from the start. If you want to know the actual shortest path, you would also store the preceding node on the path for each node of the graph. 

I might be misunderstanding -- I do not know the role of the nearestUnvisitedNode method.